# C Bubble Sort Integer Array - Output Issue

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, integer, bubble-sort

Newbie Here.

For my C programming class, I'm required to use bubble sort to sort a list that's read from an input .txt file. Each line on the .txt file has a year, name, and states affected by a hurricane [year] [name] [states].

Ex:

```
1999 Floyd NC
2003 Isabel NC, VA
2004 Charley FL, SC, NC
2004 Frances FL
...etc.
```

The program needs to sort the list by year while keeping all the data lines correct (keep the relative array elements together). My integer array bubble sort works fine except for one issue- one line of data is off to the side of the list. Here's an example output of this issue:

```
    1960    Donna    FL, NC
    1969    Camille  MS     1972    Agnes    FL
    1983    Alicia   TX
    2004    Charley  FL, SC, NC
```

The `1972 Agnes FL` line is almost correct, but for some reason prints off to the side rather than right under the previous line.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_HURCS 30

int main() {
    FILE *hurricaneData;
    int year[MAX_HURCS];
    char name[MAX_HURCS][50];
    char states[MAX_HURCS][50];
    int i = 0, j;
    int count = 0;
    int sort;
    int tempYear;
    char tempName[50];
    char tempStates[50];

    if ((hurricaneData = fopen("hurricanes2.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open file");
    }

    while ((fscanf(hurricaneData, "%d %s", &year[i], &name[i]) != EOF)
        && (fgets(states[i], 50, hurricaneData) != NULL)) {
        i++;
        count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < count - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (year[j] > year[j + 1]) {
                tempYear = year[j];
                year[j] = year[j+1];
                year[j+1] = tempYear;

                strcpy(tempName, name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j], name[j+1]);
                strcpy(name[j+1], tempName);

                strcpy(tempStates, states[j]);
                strcpy(states[j], states[j+1]);
                strcpy(states[j+1], tempStates);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf(" \t%d\t%s\t%s ", year[i], name[i], states[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried this for the sorting algorithm, but I come across this same issue:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        if (year[j] > year[i]) {
            tempYear = year[i];
            year[i] = year[j];
            year[j] = tempYear;

            strcpy(tempName, name[i]);
            strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
            strcpy(name[j], tempName);

            strcpy(tempStates, states[i]);
            strcpy(states[i], states[j]);
            strcpy(states[j], tempStates);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving a \n manually in printf printf(" \t%d\t%s\t%s\n", year[i], name[i], states[i]);

Comment: Interesting. When I do that, the output list prints out in order with that data line beneath the other, its just without a newline space. So its technically correct, but I believe there's still an issue with the very last step of the sort.

Comment: This??, I think the error is that your last line in your file does not have a end of line character  so it reads upto end of file and when it print the same line it does not move to next line so either go to last line in your text file and put a endl in the last line or print a endl manually for each line, and your previous comment  I dont see a new output

Comment: @TomKarzes fgets function will read new line from the text file anyway so there is no point in giving  a extra new line after every line, the problem is that the last line in text file do not have new line.

Comment: @Anil yes, I realized that when I looked more closely.  It just seems odd to carry the newlines around when sorting.  Normally they would be stripped when reading the records, since they are not part of the data, then inserted when outputting the result.  That's the proper way to fix this.

Comment: I used fgets here because the varying length and delimiters in the "affected states" array. I believe fscanf wouldn't be able to read this part correctly. Also, adding an endline to the of the document worked.

Comment: You're not reading the data properly.  You should not be carrying newline characters around with your state strings.  They're not part of the data.  What if you wanted to printing something else *after* the states?  You couldn't, because they have newline characters.  If you're parsing the lines into fields, then you should do it properly by stripping the newline characters.  Then you wouldn't have bugs like this.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now Tom. Thank you!

Comment: Think of the newlines as record separators, rather than part of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is that your last line in your file does not have a end of line character so it reads upto end of file and when it print the same line it does not move to next line so either go to last line in your text file and put a endl in the last line or print a endl manually for each line. Another or more generic way would be to remove new line from your input, that can be done like this, while reading text do this

```
int len = strlen(states[i]);
if(len>0 && states[i][len-1] == '\n')
{
    states[i][len-1] = '\0';
}
```

this will remove all new line and then you can print them manually in printf

Comment: This is correct, I understand. Thanks so much for your help on this @Anil.

Comment: You also need to check that the length is non-zero.  The code above is not safe if it encounters an empty string with no newline.  In that case it will index past the start of the string, possibly even modifying the contents.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it. Hopefully OP will notice the fix.